# Save show hide state javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hi guys can you help me? I want to use local storage javascript. but my code is not working. I wanna save show hide state using local storage javascript, but my show hide state cannot be save, and always back to hide state when i refresh.

this is my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var showText='Show';
    var hideText='Hide';
    var is_visible = false;

    $('.toggle').prev().append(' <a href="#" class="toggleLink">'+showText+'</a>');

    $('.toggle').hide();

    $('a.toggleLink').click(function() {


        if ($(this).text()==showText) {
            localStorage.setItem('showText', true);
            $(this).text(hideText);
            $(this).parent().next('.toggle').slideDown('fast');
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem('showText', false);
            $(this).text(showText);
            $(this).parent().next('.toggle').slideUp('fast');
        }
        return false;
    });
    var hideText = localStorage.getItem('Hide') === 'false' ? false : Show;
    $('a.toggleLink').toggle(hideText);
});
```

Thank you.

*Sorry for my bad english

Comment: will be easy to help if you can create a demo and also share the html

Comment: `localStorage.getItem('Hide')`.. You didnt set any keys with `Hide` on your localStorage though

Answer (score 1):

You don‘t set the key „Hide“ in `LocalStorage`, so after your click-function it will always be `false`. You have to change this into something like:

```
var hideText = localStorage.getItem('showText') === false ? 'Hide' : 'Show';
```

Answer (score 1):

In your local storage you didn't save anything by using 'Hide' keyword. So from the following statement your local storage won't be able to take any value.

```
var hideText = localStorage.getItem('Hide') === 'false' ? false : Show;
```

So just change the 'Hide' by 'showText'.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var showText='Show';
    var hideText='Hide';
    var is_visible = false;
    $('.toggle').prev().append(' <a href="#" class="toggleLink">showText</a>');
    $('.toggle').hide();
    $('a.toggleLink').click(function() {
        if ($(this).text()==showText) {
            localStorage.setItem('showText', true);
            $(this).text(hideText);
            $(this).parent().next('.toggle').slideDown('fast');
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem('showText', false);
            $(this).text(showText);
            $(this).parent().next('.toggle').slideUp('fast');
        }
        return false;
    });
    var hideText = localStorage.getItem('showText') === 'false' ? false : Show;
    $('a.toggleLink').toggle(hideText);
});
```